# Upgrade SharePoint 2007 to 2013

Tags: 2013, 2007, migration, upgrade

I have a need to upgrade our SharePoint server from 2007 to 2013. I have read lots of articles for this migration but I still have some confuses about that. Someone can give me some suggestions for this.

Below are my current situation

- We have a Production server which using SharePoint 2007, now we have to upgrade this to SharePoint 2013 because of no support from Microsoft for 2007 version.
- We cannot do that on Production environment because we don't know when migration process finished. So there is a NEW server for doing this. After upgrade completed, we will stop current Production server and use this NEW server.

Here are what I need to do:

1. Move data to a new Database Server (DONE) - we are using SQL Server 2012 for our current SharePoint 2007
2. Move current Web app to our NEW SharePoint server (the same version 2007 with current server) to prepare for upgrade process?
3. Upgrade SharePoint on this new server to 2010 version. I must install SP 2010 manually OR this is automatic step by using a function in current SP 2007?
4. After upgrade to 2010, we will upgrade it to 2013 by doing the same steps as from 2007 to 2010. The same question as step 3.

Thank you in advance for your help/suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Move current Web app to our NEW SharePoint server (the same version 2007 with current server) to prepare for upgrade process?

Yes! If you have created a backup and restored the entire farm with its service applications, you are on your way to backup restore and restore web applications. See [Back up and restore Web applications by using built-in tools (Office SharePoint Server 2007)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263097(v=office.12).aspx)

> Upgrade SharePoint on this new server to 2010 version. I must install SP 2010 manually OR this is automatic step by using a function in current SP 2007?

This is a manual process where you run the

1) PrerequisiteInstaller.exe on all servers in the farm.

2) When this is done, you need to run Setup.exe and install SharePoint 2010 on  all servers in the farm.

3) Run SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard on all servers, which completes the installation

Now it’s time to check that all content and functionality is present and working. You probably need help from the organization to verify everything. See more details in [Upgrade in place to SharePoint Server 2010](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263212%28v=office.14%29.aspx#prereq)

> After upgrade to 2010, we will upgrade it to 2013 by doing the same steps as from 2007 to 2010. The same question as step 3.

Migration to 2013 from 2010 differs a lot. The only option you have is detach attach method.

First you need to create (install) the new 2013 farm and copy all the databases (service databases and content databases) to the new farm. Next step is to upgrade the service applications and make sure they are idle before you upgrade content databases. The last step is to upgrade the site collections which could be done by site owners or by an administrator. See [Overview of the upgrade process to SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262483.aspx)

Comment: Thanks BennySkogberg for your helpful info. I have a question about this upgarde : I must install both SharePoint 2010 & 2013 so I have to buy 2 versions from Microsoft ? If yes, it's not fair. The result I want to receive is to use SharePoint 2013 for my company.

Comment: @user2809372 Well I guess that's why you can use a [free trial license for 180 days](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16631), which will give you plenty of time to migrate to 2013.

Comment: @user2809372 Glad I could help :-)